# EF5 Convert Returned List<string> to its Proper Type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework 5, the following code is invalid since I'm trying to cast a `List<string>` to `List<TRK_USER>`. Makes sense.

```
List<TRK_USER> userList = db.TRK_USER.Select(t => t.USER_FIRST).ToList();
```

However, I would like to maintain the type of the TRK_USER object. What I would hope/expect is that I could convert that `List<string>` to a `List<TRK_USER>` and just get nulls for all of the missing properties. So in this case I would have a `List<TRK_USER>` where only USER_FIRST is populated with data. Is this possible with some magical extension method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that TRK_USER has a parameterless constructor, you could do:

```
List<TRK_USER> userList = db.TRK_USER
            .Select(t => new TRK_USER{ USER_FIRST = t.USER_FIRST})
            .ToList();
```

But why would you want to do that?

```
List<string> userFirstNamesList = db.TRK_USER
            .Select(t => t.USER_FIRST)
            .ToList();
```

would give the exact same information, just without unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thanks - I agree it gives the same information, but I lose intellisense on the object.

Comment: Why do you need intellisense if the object is basically empty, and you only use the first name? BTW, the class and field name are a long way off any accepted C# standard.

Comment: I was just putting forth a simple example. Obviously more complicated objects would be more useful. And the class/field name? You can thank Oracle's EF implementation.

Comment: Yes :) USER_FIRST has a distinct Orable smell :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<TRK_USER> userList =
      db.TRK_USER
            .Select(t => new TRK_USER{USER_FIRST = t.USER_FIRST})
            .ToList();
```